# Drawing pictures with pstricks and including ps-pictures refused by TeX-maker on MacBookPro (Sierra))

Tags: pstricks, texmaker, mactex

I have a MacBookPro, Sierra, and use TeX-Maker (for Mac).

There were initially some troubles with TeX-maker and El Capitan;
they have been resolved, apparently. But ever since, TeX-maker refuses:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52yKH.png) to draw pictures with `pstricks`; and
[2] to accept ps-pictures in `\includegraphics[width=10cm]{birds.ps}`.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52yKH.png)
Here is a simple LaTeX source file that keeps crashing:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{pstricks,epsfig,graphicx}
 %
 \begin{document}
 \noindent Venn diagrams:
 \begin{center}\begin{picture}(180,20)(0,0)
 \psset{unit=0.5ex, linewidth=1pt}
 \psellipse(23,20)(90,10)
 \end{picture}\end{center}%
 \end{document}
```

Error message by TeX-Maker:

\c@lor@to@ps
l.11 \psellipse(23,20)(90,10)
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.

[2] Here is a simple LaTeX-source file that keeps crashing too:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{pstricks,epsfig,graphicx} 
 %
 \begin{document}
 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=10cm]{birds.ps}
 \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

Error message TeX-Maker:

LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .ps.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.

Before El Capitan, this all went fine. Since El Capitan, and Sierra,
problems [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52yKH.png) and [2] irritatingly persist.

I have a screen shot of my TeX-Maker configuration, which can be seen below:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! To attach an image file to your post, click on the mountain icon in the  tool bar of the edit window. Note TeXmaker refuses nothing, it's the compiler. Do you compile with latex, pdflatex, xelatex?

Comment: Welcome! I get your error messages when compiling the documents with `pdflatex` (which is the wrong compiler), but it works when using `latex` and `dvips`. I guess you have to switch to the correct tool chain somewhere in the settings. (Can't tell you where since I don't use TeX-Maker.)

Comment: It also work with `pdflatex`, if load `auto-pst-pdf` (*after* pstricks`) and if you  launch the compiler with the `-shell-escape` switch. Alrernatively, you can compile with `xelatex`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `xelatex` and do not mix the `picture` environment with `pstricks`
commands. Here is the setting for TeXShop.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am also using macOS Sierra in a MacBookPro (from 2014). Following the good suggestions in the comments, I perfectly compiled your first example without changing a single line; and I could also compile your second example using an old picture of mine in ps format that I renamed to `birds.ps`. The only thing I had to do was making sure I was compiling with `LaTex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` (I do not know if there are other ways of compiling that will also work). You can see a screenshot below.

[image]
[image]

I think this answers your question. Beyond that, let me also give some advise here:

1. There are editors out there that can detect automatically for you the best compilation method for your document. This is my case and this is how I could determine how to compile your document. I will not give the name of such LaTex editor here because it is not what you are asking for; but if you are interested, let me know.
2. Although some may perfectly disagree with me, I have a preference for including external images as pdfs (for some strange reason, some mathematical symbols never seem to be as I want them when using `ps`or `eps` files; but they always look good in pdf).

Comment: Thnx Héctor. The refusal happens if I only use the LaTeX-command (without + dvips + ps2pdf), for both LaTeX-files. As soon as I delete the ps-stuff, everything works. I also prefer to use PdfLatex, with pdf-pictures (changing ps-pictures into pdf's is easy), but this doesn't work with ps-stuff. Drawing simple pictures without pstricks seems difficult in LaTeX.